# jQuery: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: (bunch of photo caption text data)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am attempting to add text from a jQuery array at a given point to my webpage. The page is set up so that when I click on a thumbnail, a larger image and caption data are to show on the page, however the caption text is not showing. `$(caption[this.id]).text().appendTo('#images');` is where the error comes from, though if I do a simple DOM.write with the `(caption[this.id]).text()`, the words will show on the page.

```
// App variables
    var filename = [];
    var caption = [];
    var id = [];
    var counter = 0;
    var thumbs = $([]);
    var images = $([]);

//Make an AJAX call to load the XML file data
    $.ajax({
        url: 'gallery.xml',
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: function (data) {
            $(data).find('gallery').each(function () {
                // Gather the image filenames
                $(data).find('image filename').each(function () {
                    counter++;

                    id.push(counter);
                    filename.push($(this).text());
                });
                //console.log(filename);
                // Gather the image captions
                $(data).find('image caption').each(function () {
                    caption.push($(this).text());
                });
            });
            // Run the thumbnail loading procedure when the AJAX call has completed
            loadThumbs();
            loadImages();
        },
        error: function () {
            // Failure alert if XML was not loaded
            alert("XML file couldn't load...");
        }
    });

    // Loop through filename list and create large image for each entry
    var loadImages = function() {
        $.each(filename, function (_, src) {
            images = images.add(
                $('<img />', {src: 'images/' + src, class: 'largeImage', height: '100px', width: '100px'})
            );
        });

        // Add first image to default
        $(images[0]).appendTo('#images')
    };

// Do some shit when image is clicked... 
    $( document ).on( "click", "img", function() {
        // Empty viewing DIV and create a new large-scale version of the image for viewing
        $('#images').empty();
        $(images[this.id]).appendTo('#images');

        //THIS IS WHERE ERROR COMES FROM
        // Add text to <span> to solve error?
        $(caption[this.id]).text().appendTo('#images');
    });
```

The error is specifically: [image: jQuery Syntax Error]

I can add all of the JS code if there is not enough here to understand. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing the caption text to jQuery:

```
$(caption[this.id])
```

The library is trying to parse it as a CSS selector, and it can't so it throws the error.

You could do several things to make it work, and your suggestion in the comment is a good one:

```
$("<span/>", { text: caption[this.id] }).appendTo("#images");
```

Comment: Excellent! I was thinking to use a `<span>`, but I simply couldn't remember how to code what I wanted to accomplish. Thank you!